# Return HTTP-JSON data from asyncTask to Activity via listener

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to return JSON data from my AsyncTask extended class to my Activity.
My activity code is as follows:

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements JSONListener{

        private JSONObject jsonData = null;

        @Override
        public void JSONFeedBack(JSONObject jsonData) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            this.jsonData = jsonData;
            Log.e("JSON check in JSONFeedBack(): ", jsonData.toString()  );
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            new JsonObj(this).execute("http://xml/url");

        }
    }
```

My JSONListener is as follows:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

public interface JSONListener {
    void JSONFeedBack(JSONObject jsonObj);
}
```

And my asyncTask class is as follows:

```
public class JsonObj extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>{
    MainActivity activity;
    JSONListener jsonListener;
    int tid;
    String term;

    public JsonObj(JSONListener jsonListener){
        this.jsonListener = jsonListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... url) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DefaultHttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url[0]);
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        // Depends on your web service
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            // json is UTF-8 by default
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON-Test [RESULT]: ", result);
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);


        } catch (Exception e) { 
            Log.e("JSON-Test [exception]: ", e.toString());
        }
        finally {
            try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
        }

        return jsonObject;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        this.jsonListener.JSONFeedBack(result);
        Log.e("OnPostExecute TEST: ", result.toString());

    }
}
```

The actual JSON data fetch by HTTP-REQUEST is as follows:

```
[
{
"data": {
"term": "All Nations Praise",
"tid": "10"
}
},
{
"data": {
"term": "Classified Advertisements",
"tid": "16"
}
},
{
"data": {
"term": "Kid&#039;s",
"tid": "11"
}
},
{
"data": {
"term": "KT Creative",
"tid": "9"
}
},
{
"data": {
"term": "KT Diary",
"tid": "8"
}
},
{
"data": {
"term": "Live at the Coronet",
"tid": "14"
}
},
{
"data": {
"term": "Situations Vacant",
"tid": "15"
}
},
{
"data": {
"term": "X:Change",
"tid": "13"
}
},
{
"data": {
"term": "Youth",
"tid": "12"
}
}
]
```

So, I get a null-pointer exception at my call to `Log.e("JSON check in JSONFeedBack(): ", jsonData.toString());` in my `JSONFeedBack` in my Activity class.

I have confirmed the JSON data is fetched in the AsynchClass but my attempts to send it to the activity keeps resulting in the null-pointer exception.

Comment: have you tried to put `Log.e("OnPostExecute TEST: ",result.toString());` before `this.jsonListener.JSONFeedBack(result);` to be sure that `result` is not null?

Answer (score 0):

I have just ran your code changing the url with one of my service and works fine... I think there is a problem when you create the `JSONObject`

```
jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

are you sure you don't log this line:

```
Log.e("JSON-Test [exception]: ", e.toString());
```

i.e. if I use this url http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json i get an exception creating the `JSONObject` and then the NPE you get.

I'm pretty sure that the communication between AsynchTask and Activity works, the problem is in your response or how you parse it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am very confused the code worked of you and it may confirm a suspission that there's something wrong with my json data. Let me know what you think. I pasted the JSON output in question

Answer (score 0):

Do not add new line character to your Json string.

```
 String line = null;
     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
     sb.append(line); // remove + "\n" here
 }
```

Edit: You should see an exception because of this at your `Log.e("JSON-Test [exception]: ", e.toString());`